# Change javac path from ant

Tags: java, ant, javac

Can I specify the javac path from within ant, when using fork ? I'm asking this because I need to run a script from an automation framwork(cruisecontrol) , however when I use fork, it uses jdk of a lower version bundled with the framework. Hence is there any way I can specify a different path for javac?

Comment: See Jeremy's answer; plus, to specify the path to javac you need to set the `executable` attribute of the `javac` task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `build.compiler` system property, or set the `compiler` property on the `javac` task:

> The compiler implementation to use. If this attribute is not set, the value of the build.compiler property, if set, will be used. Otherwise, the default compiler for the current VM will be used.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

Answer (score 0):

set JAVA_HOME.  If you want to use multiple JVMs in a single build that's not possible, you would need to run two ant commands and set the JAVA_HOME before each one.